# Using 2 QueryParams to return an object requiring 2 different variables

Tags: java, html, mysql

I'm writing a special permission forms program using MySQL, Javascript, and HTML code, which both respond to. I'm doing all of this using singleton pattern access and facade code(s) in java, and a services code, which responds to the singleton pattern codes.

**I'm trying To retrieve a form (AKA 1 Result) by the variables, courseDept & courseNm.**

This is a snippet of code I'm using to do all this:

**FormDataFacade.java code snippet:**

```
@Path("/specialPermissions/sp")
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response getSpecialPermissionFormByDeptAndRoomNm(@QueryParam("courseDept") String theDept, @QueryParam("courseNm") String theNm) 
throws NamingException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
//Referenciation to FormDataFacade class.
FormDataFacade iFacade = FormDataFacade.getInstance();

int intNm = 0;
try {
intNm = Integer.parseInt(theNm);
}catch (NumberFormatException FAIL) {
intNm = 1;
}

//Aiming for forms with matching departments & room numbers by calling FormDataFacade
//method, getSpecialPermissionFormByDeptAndRoomNm.
SpecialPermissionForms[] orgaForm = iFacade.getSpecialPermissionFormByDeptAndRoomNm(theDept, intNm);

//Json String Representation...
if (orgaForm != null)
{
 Gson neoArcadia = new Gson();
 String result = neoArcadia.toJson(orgaForm);

 //Json String added to response message body...
 ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(result, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
 rb.status(200); //HTTP Status code has been set!
 return rb.build(); //Creating & Returning Response.
}
else
{ //In case of finding no form data for the procedure...
 return Response.status(700).build();
}
}
```

**FormDataServices.java code snippet:**

```
public SpecialPermissionForms[] getSpecialPermissionFormByDeptAndRoomNm(String theDept, int theNm) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
 Connection con = zeon.getConnection();
 PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT formID, studentName, courseDept, courseNm, semester, year, reasonCode FROM spforms WHERE courseDept = ? & courseNm = ?");
 pstmt.setString(1, theDept);
 pstmt.setInt(2, theNm);
 ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

 SpecialPermissionForms[] neoForm = new SpecialPermissionForms[50];
 int current = 0;

  while (rs.next())
  {
   int formID3 = rs.getInt("formID");
   String studentName3 = rs.getString("studentName");
   String courseDept3 = rs.getString("courseDept");
   String courseNm3 = rs.getString("courseNm");
   String semester3 = rs.getString("semester");
   int year3 = rs.getInt("year");
   String reasonCode3 = rs.getString("reasonCode");
   SpecialPermissionForms neo = new SpecialPermissionForms(formID3, studentName3, courseDept3, courseNm3, semester3, year3, reasonCode3);
   neoForm[current] = neo;
   current++;
  }

  if (current > 0)
  {
   neoForm = Arrays.copyOf(neoForm, current);
   return neoForm;
  }

  else
  {
   return null;
  }
}
```

**Forms.html code snippet which both pieces of java code respond to:**

```
$("#btnOneName").click(function() {
alert("clicked");
var inputId1=document.getElementById("t_specialFormCourseDept").value;
var inputId2=document.getElementById("t_specialFormCourseNm").value;
var theData = "courseDept=" + inputId1 + "&" + "courseNm=" + inputId2;
alert("Sending: " + theData);
var theUrl = "http://localhost:8080/onlineforms/services/enrollment/specialPermissions/sp?courseDept=&courseNm="+ theData;
$.ajax( {
url: theUrl,
type: "GET",
dataType: "text",
success: function(result) {
alert("success");
var neoForm = JSON.parse(result);
alert(neoForm);
var output="<h3>Current Form Lists:</h3>";
output += "<ul>";
for (var current = 0; current < neoForm.length; current++)
{
output += "<li>" + neoForm[current].formID + ": " + neoForm[current].studentName + " (" + neoForm[current].courseDept + " - " + neoForm[current].courseNm + ") " + 
        " (" + neoForm[current].semester +  " - " + neoForm[current].year + ") " + " - " + neoForm[current].reasonCode + "</li>";
}
output += "</ul>";
alert(output);
$("#p_retrieveOneName").html(output); 
},
error:function(xhr) {
alert("error");
$("#p_retrieveOneName").html("Error:"+xhr.status+" "+xhr.statusText);}
} );
});
});
```

Now, when I go test this code in my webservice after successfully compiling it, it does work, however it retrieves everything, including the specific results I was searching for - I only want to return the results I have specifically searched for and nothing else. What exactly am I doing wrong here in these snippets of code?
Any suggestions or steps in the right direction are highly welcome.